# PHP: want to put variable and string in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to put variable and string in mysql.

The json code was output by the API.

**json view:**

```
Array(
    [body] => Array
        (
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [bizesId] => 333333
                            [lon] => 00.000000
                            [lat] => 00.000000
                        )

                )

)
```

**PHP code:**

```
    for ($i=0; $i<=1000; $i++) {

  foreach($result_json['body']['items'] as $arr){
      if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO TEST (`num`,'market',`lon`,`lat`) VALUES ('". $arr['bizesId'] ."','test','". $arr['lon'] ."','". $arr['lat'] ."')")){
      }
  }
 }
```

Data can not be saved.

Comment: Please read about [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [bound parameters](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [this page](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: Are you gettung any error

Comment: You are mixing ` and `'`in your sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
  INSERT INTO TEST (`num`,'market',`lon`,`lat`) VALUES ('$arr['bizesId']','test',' $arr['lon']','$arr['lat']'
```

Try this.
and also change table name if it is in Lowercase write - **test**

Comment: error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Comment: ok then use your query just put  $result_json['body']['items'][0] as $arr)

Comment: Despite the revision, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: The `'`around market will cause the error. Try `

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Thank you.

INSERT INTO TEST (`num`,`market`,`lon`,`lat`) VALUES ...

Answer (score 0):

**replace 'market' with `market`. Foll code works fine**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'xxxx';
$DB = 'test';
$host = 'localhost';


$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $DB);
$result_json['body']['items'][0] = ['bizesId'=>34, 'lon'=>34, 'lat'=>23];

foreach($result_json['body']['items'] as $arr){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO TEST_INSERT (`num`,`market`,`lon`,`lat`) VALUES ('". $arr['bizesId'] ."','test','". $arr['lon'] ."','". $arr['lat'] ."')";
      if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
      }
      else
      {
        echo $sql.'<br>';
      }
  }
```